# Spark: counting on a window not working for millisecond

Tags: pyspark, timestamp, apache-spark-sql, windowing

You can create a window to count the number of times a record has occurred in the last 7 days. However, if you try to look at the number of times the record has occurred on a millisecond level, it breaks down.

In short, the below function `df.timestamp.astype('Timestamp').cast("long")` only converts the timestamp up to the grain of a second to a long. It ignores the millisecond. How do you turn the entire timestamp, milliseconds included, into a long. You need the value to be a long so that it'll work with the window.

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
        ("a", "u8u", "2018-02-02 05:46:41.438357"),
        ("a", "u8u", "2018-02-02 05:46:41.439377"),
        ("a", "a3a", "2018-02-02 09:48:34.081818"),
        ("a", "a3a", "2018-02-02 09:48:34.095586"),
        ("a", "g8g", "2018-02-02 09:48:56.006206"),
        ("a", "g8g", "2018-02-02 09:48:56.007974"),
        ("a", "9k9", "2018-02-02 12:50:48.000000"),
        ("a", "9k9", "2018-02-02 12:50:48.100000"),
], ["person_id", "session_id", "timestamp"])


df = df.withColumn('unix_ts',df.timestamp.astype('Timestamp').cast("long"))
df = df.withColumn("DayOfWeek",F.date_format(df.timestamp, 'EEEE'))

w = Window.partitionBy('person_id','DayOfWeek').orderBy('unix_ts').rangeBetween(-86400*7,-1)
df = df.withColumn('count',F.count('unix_ts').over(w))
df.sort(df.unix_ts).show(20,False)


+---------+----------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----+
|person_id|session_id|timestamp                 |unix_ts   |DayOfWeek|count|
+---------+----------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----+
|a        |u8u       |2018-02-02 05:46:41.438357|1517572001|Friday   |0    |
|a        |u8u       |2018-02-02 05:46:41.439377|1517572001|Friday   |0    |
|a        |a3a       |2018-02-02 09:48:34.081818|1517586514|Friday   |2    |
|a        |a3a       |2018-02-02 09:48:34.095586|1517586514|Friday   |2    |
|a        |g8g       |2018-02-02 09:48:56.006206|1517586536|Friday   |4    |
|a        |g8g       |2018-02-02 09:48:56.007974|1517586536|Friday   |4    |
|a        |9k9       |2018-02-02 12:50:48.000000|1517597448|Friday   |6    |
|a        |9k9       |2018-02-02 12:50:48.100000|1517597448|Friday   |6    |
+---------+----------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----+
```

The count should be 0,1,2,3,4,5... instead of 0,0,2,2,4,4,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp) to convert the string column to a timestamp instead of casting to `long`.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.select(
    "timestamp",
    F.unix_timestamp(F.col("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").alias("unix_ts")
).show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------+----------+
#|timestamp                 |unix_ts   |
#+--------------------------+----------+
#|2018-02-02 05:46:41.438357|1517568839|
#|2018-02-02 05:46:41.439377|1517568840|
#|2018-02-02 09:48:34.081818|1517582995|
#|2018-02-02 09:48:34.095586|1517583009|
#|2018-02-02 09:48:56.006206|1517582942|
#|2018-02-02 09:48:56.007974|1517582943|
#|2018-02-02 12:50:48.862644|1517594710|
#|2018-02-02 12:50:49.981848|1517594830|
#+--------------------------+----------+
```

The second argument to `unix_timestamp()` is the format string. In your case, use `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"`.

---

The corresponding change applied to your code would be:

```python
df = df.withColumn(
    'unix_ts',
    F.unix_timestamp(F.col("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
)
df = df.withColumn("DayOfWeek", F.date_format(df.timestamp, 'EEEE'))

w = Window.partitionBy('person_id','DayOfWeek').orderBy('unix_ts').rangeBetween(-86400*7,-1)
df = df.withColumn('count',F.count('unix_ts').over(w))
df.sort(df.unix_ts).show(20,False)
#+---------+----------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----+
#|person_id|session_id|timestamp                 |unix_ts   |DayOfWeek|count|
#+---------+----------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----+
#|a        |u8u       |2018-02-02 05:46:41.438357|1517568839|Friday   |0    |
#|a        |u8u       |2018-02-02 05:46:41.439377|1517568840|Friday   |1    |
#|a        |g8g       |2018-02-02 09:48:56.006206|1517582942|Friday   |2    |
#|a        |g8g       |2018-02-02 09:48:56.007974|1517582943|Friday   |3    |
#|a        |a3a       |2018-02-02 09:48:34.081818|1517582995|Friday   |4    |
#|a        |a3a       |2018-02-02 09:48:34.095586|1517583009|Friday   |5    |
#|a        |9k9       |2018-02-02 12:50:48.862644|1517594710|Friday   |6    |
#|a        |9k9       |2018-02-02 12:50:49.981848|1517594830|Friday   |7    |
#+---------+----------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----+
```

Comment: This is better, but I think it still has an issue with smaller timeframes. For example, replace the last two rows with these two and it'll be 6,6 instead of 6,7
("a", "9k9", "2018-02-02 12:50:48.000000"),
("a", "9k9", "2018-02-02 12:50:48.000001"),

Comment: @MicahPearce you can `orderBy('Timestamp')` in your Window function to get the desired ordering.

Comment: The windowing function doesn't work when you order by 'Timestamp'. It errors out saying that the Order By clause needs to be a numeric type.

Comment: That works, but you lose the 7 day lookback which is important. Now, wiht the rangeBetween you've helped me get an accuracy up to '.001' which is better than I had it before.I'll have to see if this is good enough.